# Linux distribution for LaTex and begin coding on C

Tags: linux-distribution

I have Intel Celeron 1.1GHz and 4GB ram currently with w10 installed but I'm looking for a a linux distribution that is lighter and won't force updates into my poor machine.

It will mainly be used to browser online, write text on LaTeX, read pdf and code on C (I'm not a programmer but sometimes I write a simple code and need to compile/test it) outside of that the most I would ask for is to emulate game boy (but it's almost irrelevant). Moreover I would really appreciate if it was stable and friendly to install. I've read some posts here and LUbuntu or XUbuntu seems to be a great option, but I've never used any and I dont know if any Tex distribution is compatible so I'm better off asking for help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned Lubuntu and Xubuntu, and both will do the job just fine, though heavy multitasking may see it take a hit on performance.

Regarding your LaTeX distribution: For any Linux distribution based on Ubuntu, you can simply run this command to install LaTeX:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

This will install the packages for standard LaTeX use. You can then render your TeX files by running:

```
$ pdflatex file.tex
```

This will create a pdf file names `file.pdf` from the input file `file.text`.